# Need to alter a 3 V - 4.2 V output to a 1 V - 5 V input

Tags: voltage-divider, voltage-measurement

I'm currently using a bargraph meter with a scale of 1 V - 5 V to read the voltage of a lithium cell. I run the cell between 3 V and 4.2 V, so although this works, I'm only utilising a small amount of the bargraph.

The meter itself is separately powered by a 12 V supply, so is just reading the battery, not also powered by it.

I'm looking for a solution that will allow me to convert the 3 V - 4.2 V range I'm reading from the battery to a 1 V - 5 V input to the meter in order to utilise the full range of the meter's bargraph.

Thank you all for any solutions in advance.

Comment: Aside from the battery, is 12V your only supply?

Comment: Please post data on the meter you are using.  Data sheet, vandor site link, etc.

Comment: A problem may be that there's a difference between a scholastic, idealized answer (which can be one thing) and an instrumentation answer (which is another thing.) How accurately do you need to make this conversion? How repeatably, if you were to build two or ten such devices? (I suspect precision isn't an issue, so I won't ask.) Simplistic answers using groups of resistors don't take into account the resistor tolerances. And these can have very significant impacts on the results. So it's important to know fully what you actually require.

Comment: Ideally I need an answer with a circuit diagram that's easily followable by a layman showing components with descriptions in a way that I can easily go and source them and get soldering! This is a one off project that needs to give a reasonable working precision, within +- 3% or so.

Answer (score 4):

You need amplification since:

$$\frac{5-1}{4.2-3} = 3,333$$

So you could use a differential amplifier:

[image]

to get the desired result:

[image]

V1 is the voltage you want to read. V2 shifts the output up and V3 is there to match the minimum input voltage. Both V2 and V3 can be provided by simple voltage references like a TL431 and you may need precision resistors to avoid using trimpots to match the resistor pairs (R1 = R5 and R4 = R6).

Edit: assuming a bargraph with 10 steps, a \$(5-1) / 10 / 2 = 200 mV \$ error would be acceptable. A random simulation with 10000 runs using 1% resistors showed a maximum error of 150 mV.

Comment: The two references should not be necessary - in fact this operation needs no references at all.

Comment: @Reinderien I think you are assuming that the 12 V supply is 12.000 V and rock solid. This answer allows for variation in that supply voltage, which I think is the more appropriate solution.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Even if you couldn't rely on the supply at all, you would only need one reference, not two

Comment: @Reinderien. Your suggestion would be to replace the lower reference by a resistor divider from the higher one?

Comment: @vangelo Yes; edited. For the divided-single-reference, a reference of at least 3.909V is needed to satisfy the OP's new voltage requirements

Comment: @Reinderien. Thank you for clarifying. That means R5 above would also have to be adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need - and should not introduce - more reference voltage supplies than you have to. In this case you do not need any, other than the existing voltage supply. Note that this assumes a sufficiently accurate supply; if that isn't the case then you'll need to get more creative.

Just have a non-inverting amp with gain of 5.715 and offset of -18.4 (for your new input range of 3.4-4.1 V). Any ratiometric multiple of this circuit will do:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIDlMw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: dc sweep]

Standard resistor values that get you pretty close are shown below. Given that this is a slow-varying signal from a battery you'll also want filtration; the cheap and easy option is a parallel cap:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8AVLE.png)</sup>

[image: transients]

Time constant to taste. I doubt you'll care about any variations faster than 50 ms.

This topology is governed by the following equations, *a* and *b* shown for your new voltages of 3.4 and 4.1:

$$
b = \frac {R_3}{R_2} =
\frac
{
  (V_{cc} - V_{i1})(V_{i2} - V_{o2}) - (V_{cc}- V_{i2})(V_{i1} - V_{o1})
}
{
  (V_{cc} - V_{i2})V_{i1} - (V_{cc} - V_{i1})V_{i2}
}
\approx 3.179
$$

$$
a = \frac {R_3}{R_1} = 
\frac
{ V_i (b + 1) - V_o }
{V_{cc} - V_i} \approx 1.536 
$$

If your supply is insufficiently accurate, you can use the same topology replacing the 12V supply with any reference above 3.9V. You can find standard references at 4.096V or 5V for instance. With a 4.096V reference, R1-R3 as 25.5k, 536k and 115k would produce the same result.

You ask which op-amp to use. This isn't a shopping site so specific device recommendations are usually discouraged, but the "type" of op-amp you'll want to look for really varies based on whether you want to optimize for ease of solder, low power consumption, etc. A reasonable guess (without knowing all of your design parameters) is the TLV271, which is rail-to-rail and accepts up to 16V supply. You don't really have bandwidth constraints, so your only constraints will be output current, single-ended supply voltage, single-ended (non-differential) output, maybe power consumption??, and maybe package size??. The TLV271 comes in a variety of packages from 8-SOIC and smaller.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Which Op-amp would you recommend as most suitable please?

Comment: Without knowing anything else about your application, something cheap and general purpose like the NCV33201VDR2G

Comment: Thanks for your continuing help. I'm now just making up a component list to get what I need to build this circuit. One last question, what type of capacitor would you recommend as being most suitable in this instance?

Comment: Ceramic cap. It'll be inexpensive and the tolerance doesn't matter all that much.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. One last question, if I change the Vin range to 3.4 - 4.1V, can you advise what values I would then need to use for R1,2,&3 please?

Comment: @Paulie68 Edited, and including equations so you can adjust this yourself

Comment: Aren't you implicitly using the 12V supply as a reference? This circuit appears to be highly sensitive to changes in that voltage, and I'm not sure it makes any sense to use precision resistors if the supply voltage can vary by 5%.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Yes; good point. I've added a little nuance to indicate that that's the case.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if your device is using an LM3914 dot/bar graph LED driver. If so you may be able to modify it to get the range you want.

[image]

*Figure 1. The LM3914 dot/bar graph display.*

The LM3914 makes your task very simple. Set up voltage dividers to feed R<sub>LO</sub> at 3 V and R<sub>HI</sub> at 4.5 V and the bar or dot will scale linearly between those two values.
See the [LM3914 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3914.pdf) for details.